# Spring Boot doesn't work custom JPA request

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Having this code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM trainings t ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 8", nativeQuery = true)
List<Training> findRandom();
```

Getting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

When executing this code:

```
System.out.println(trainingRepo.findRandom());
```

Where is my problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: have you tested this query on db lvl?

Comment: You don't return the id field? Why aren't you just doing `select *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use "t" here because it's not JPQL but native query (you've set `nativeQuery = true`)

Replace the query with `SELECT * FROM trainings ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 8`

Comment: or just replace `SELECT t` with `SELECT t.*`